# How to add two values in a registry with batch script?

Tags: batch-file, registry, batch-processing, safe-mode

I want to edit the registry key below...

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon
```

The default data for valuename `Shell` is `explorer.exe`

I want to edit to be like `explorer.exe,Myapp1,Myapp2`

I did it manually, but is it possible to do it with a batch script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:
`REG ADD [ROOT\]RegKey /v ValueName [/t DataType] [/S Separator] [/d Data] [/f]`

in your batch to change/add registry keys. So it would be:

`reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v Shell /t REG_SZ /d "explorer.exe,Myapp1,Myapp2" /f`

For more details refer to:
http://ss64.com/nt/reg.html

Comment: Really appreciate your help. but unfortunately after running this script dont see any change in shell value data.

Comment: Can you post your script here...? Strange, I've tested it on my computer and it works paste `reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v Shell /t REG_SZ /d "explorer.exe,Myapp1,Myapp2" /f` into notepad and save it as TEST.bat then try it

Comment: @echo off

reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v Shell /t REG_SZ /d "explorer.exe,C:\Program Files\User Timer\Timer.exe" /f

Comment: also, do you have administrator privileges?

Comment: As i told you before i am the only user and i have admin privilege...... can you post the exact script you used?

Comment: Yes sorry for repeating my question, there was a delay before receiving your reply... Well I'm stumped, I've tried your: `reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v Shell /t REG_SZ /d "explorer.exe,C:\Program Files\User Timer\Timer.exe" /f ` on my machine successfully... You have created a batch file right? Not just a notepad text file named "TEST.bat"?

Comment: yes i saved it as .bat not .txt ..... and the file run successfully but no changes in reg value.  did you check your re value change manually? i am using 32bit window 7.... is there anything got to do with os version?

Comment: No, I don't think OS version matters. Just to be sure, open regedit -> click "edit" in the menu bar -> click "permissions..." -> in Group or user names: click "Administrators" check that the "Full control" box under allow is ticked.

Comment: ...also try left-click on the batch and "Run as Admin...". You may also want to check the batch file associations.